# Custom Toggle Play/Pause Button YouTube API Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, youtube-api

I've encountered an interesting conundrum with my code using YouTube API. I am using a custom play pause button to control the embedded YouTube video. The icon switches from play to pause when clicked using this HTML:

```
<div class="media-play-btn-container" id="play-pause-toggle">
     <div class="play-pause-ring"></div> //circle around play/pause icon
     <a id="media-toggle" href=""><i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i></a>
</div>
```

and this JS:

```
//toogle the play-pause button
$('#play-pause-toggle').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //the ion-pause is pulled from ionicons icons CDN
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('ion-ios-play').toggleClass('ion-pause');
});
```

This toggle should also control the starting and stopping of the youtube player as well. Right now, if I click the play button it starts the video, if I hit the pause button, it pauses the video (as it should). HOWEVER, if I were to click the play button again, nothing happens! Here's my YouTube API Code I've written:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    //media-toggle is div ID for the play/pause icons
    $('#media-toggle').click(function (event) {
        player.playVideo();
    });
    //this is for custom progress bar, please disregard
    time_total = convert_to_mins_and_secs(player.getDuration(), 1);
    loopy();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
//this is code for custom progress bar
if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    console.log("END!");
    clearTimeout(timeout_setter);
    document.getElementById("progress-bar-bottom").style.cssText = "transition: none;";
} else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    console.log("PLAYING");
    loopy();
    document.getElementById("progress-bar-bottom").style.cssText = "transition: all 1s linear 0s;";
} else {
    console.log(event.data);
}
// ==== HERE IS RELEVANT CODE ==== //
var state = player.getPlayerState();
if (state = 1) {
    $('#media-toggle').click(function (event) {
        player.pauseVideo();
    });
} else {
    $('#media-toggle').click(function (event) {
        player.playVideo();
    });
}
}
```

What can I do to fix this problem? Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: `if (state = 1)` , common mistake should use `==` instead

Comment: Oh goodness, wow. Thanks for catching my error :)